# Limit geth/parity node synchronization network usage

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, parity

It is possible to limit the network usage of geth/parity while updating my node?

I want to be able to update (slowly, this doesn't matter), to reduce the strain on my network. Does anyone know a way to do this within geth or parity?

Comment: I think that's only possible on network level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geth` and `parity` don't include this functionality but it is possible to do this at the network level. Here's how to do this for some major OSs.

- [Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28198/how-to-limit-network-bandwidth)
- [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/135719/way-to-limit-bandwidth-of-programs-on-windows)
- [macOS](https://superuser.com/questions/126642/throttle-network-bandwidth-per-application-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 3):

Use 'trickle' - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/trickle

In Ubuntu (for example):

```
sudo apt-get install trickle
```

Then to run the geth client with upload limited to 50kb/second, simply use trickle (which executes geth for you):

```
trickle -u 50 ./geth
```

Comment: While this is a possible solution for some use cases, it doesn't answer my question.